# Variables in pl / sql. What is this code doing?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I read the book "Oracle Database Architecture Expert"

I found this code that I do not understand, I do not understand this way of writing variables. Are these global variables?

how can I do this to check the timestamp for all rows in the table, and not just the deptno 10?

```
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2> variable deptno number
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2> variable dname varchar2(14)
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2> variable loc varchar2(13)
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2> variable last_mod varchar2(50)
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2>
ops$tkyte%ORA11GR2> begin
 2 :deptno := 10;
 3 select dname, loc, to_char( last_mod, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR' )
 4 into :dname,:loc,:last_mod
 5 from dept
 6 where deptno = :deptno;
 7 end;
 8 /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: This is the second very basic SQL\*Plus question you've asked in the last day. Maybe you should familiarise yourself with the documentation before you start on Tom Kyte's fine book. [Find the docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/toc.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables have been defined in SQL*Plus. The author used them to avoid declaration within the PL/SQL anonymous block and display their values with the `PRINT` command:

```
SQL> var dname varchar2(10)
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    select dname
  3      into :dname
  4      from dept
  5      where deptno = 10;
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print dname

DNAME
--------------------------------
ACCOUNTING

SQL>
```

Another option (which uses `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to display the value) would be

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_dname varchar2(10);
  3  begin
  4    select dname
  5      into l_dname
  6      from dept
  7      where deptno = 10;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line(l_dname);
 10  end;
 11  /
ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As of *all* timestamps: you'd remove parameter (in the `WHERE` clause) but - due to many rows in a table - you'd get `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error, so you'd have to, for exmaple, do it in a loop or return ref cursor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Difference between what?

Comment: I think he could get that result with `select dname from dept where deptno = 10`

Comment: Ah! Yes, that would produce the same result.

Comment: Why did he write unnecessary variables, and a lot of code?

Comment: I wouldn't know; you'd have to ask the author (or, possibly, read the book more carefully - maybe it is already explained).